# Vuex store adding children to array... possibly javascript mistake

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuex

I'm confused and can't tell if this is a javascript mistake or vuex mistake because I don't understand what's happening.

My intention is to push new items into an existing vuex array and create a flat data structure.

What's happening is I push new items into the array but they also become children of the root item... and I don't understand how.

My code:

// mutations

```
UPDATE_NODE_LIST(state, nodeList) {
    let arrayLength = state.flattenedTreeData.length;
    let newNodeList = createNewNodeList(nodeList, arrayLength);

    console.log("state", state.flattenedTreeData)

    const mergedArrays = [...state.flattenedTreeData, ...newNodeList];

    console.log(mergedArrays)

    state.unflattenedTreeData = unflattenTree(mergedArrays);
},
```

// helper function

```
const createNewNodeList = (nodeList, arrayLength) => {
let newNode = {};

const mappedNodeList = nodeList.map(node => {
    newNode.parentId = node.parentId || null;
    newNode.name = node.name;
    newNode.monetaryValue = node.monetaryValue || 0;
    newNode.id = arrayLength += 1;
    newNode.children = [];

    return newNode
})
return mappedNodeList;
}
```

the console log of state state.flattenedTreeData before merge returns an object with the newNodelist as children, even before I merge arrays.

```
console.log(state.flattenedTreeData) =>

[
    {
        "parentId": null,
        "name": "node",
        "monetaryValue": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "parentId": 1,
                "name": "2",
                "monetaryValue": 0,
                "id": 3,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "parentId": 1,
                "name": "2",
                "monetaryValue": 0,
                "id": 3,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**** state.flattenedTreeData after merging - first node has the new nodes as children but they new nodes are also pushed into array, so it's not flat and now there are duplicates ****

```
[
    {
        "parentId": null,
        "name": "node",
        "monetaryValue": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "parentId": 1,
                "name": "2",
                "monetaryValue": 0,
                "id": 3,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "parentId": 1,
                "name": "2",
                "monetaryValue": 0,
                "id": 3,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "parentId": 1,
        "name": "2",
        "monetaryValue": 0,
        "id": 3,
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "parentId": 1,
        "name": "2",
        "monetaryValue": 0,
        "id": 3,
        "children": []
    }
]
```

**** newNodeList before attempted merge ****

```
[
{
    "parentId": 1,
    "name": "2",
    "monetaryValue": 0,
    "id": 3,
    "children": []
},
{
    "parentId": 1,
    "name": "2",
    "monetaryValue": 0,
    "id": 3,
    "children": []
}
]
```

**** state.flattenedTreeData before attempted merge ****

```
    [
    {
        "parentId": null,
        "name": "node",
        "monetaryValue": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "children": []
    }
    ]
```

Hopefully this makes sense to someone, thanks in advance for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
UPDATE_NODE_LIST(state, nodeList) 
{
  state.flatNodes = arrayFlattenRecursive([], nodeList);
  console.log(state.flatNodes);
}

function arrayFlattenRecursive(outputArray, inputArray)
{
  inputArray.forEach(item =>
  {
    arrayFlattenRecursive(outputArray, item.children);    
    outputArray.push({
      ...item,
      children: [],
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Still don't fully understand why it was automatically nesting my state properties but I think vues reactivity played a role...

Flattened before building tree myself with this function and I'll take it. Too new to up vote you but thanks again.

Comment: I don't think it is the Vue reactivity. Most likely it is because there is no recursion in your code. The children can be nested deeper than just 1 level - so you need recursion to flatten the hierarchy. Reactivity has nothing to do with this recursion.